# Running pipeline directly from the shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi does anyone knows if it is possible to lunch a pipeline from a laptop just to test it locally and make quick tests/fixes on the build locally ?
The idea is to be able to checkout from repo and lunch the pipeline locally from command line. Maybe using a native binary created with GraalVM this could be possible., and maybe it could have only a subset of the jenkins functionality just enough to run a pipeline locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I've used so far (I'm the only DevOps in our company's team) to test my pipelines locally is to download and run [jenkins.war](http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war) without any unwanted installation and/or configuration. It's a WAR package which can easily be called using `java -jar jenkins.war` and some minimal post-deployment steps. It will create a small configurations folder in your home directory. (e.g. `/home/user/.jenkins`) For Pipeline You can address it through the Jenkins menu itself.
Also, there is [Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) which you can use through your command line. It might look tedious at first but after the initial setup and first test, then the re-work on your local machine will be minimal. I've been testing my Pipelines using this solution and I've almost done nothing on Jenkins server since the initial setup.

P.S (Per OP request) : Here is an example of a request I send to my local jenkins instance for running a test pipeline on a given environment with firefox as the browser. I use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) for my API requests, I can save and edit them quite easily and gives me curl output as well. This output is made by postman:

```
    curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/Pipeline_Basic/buildWithParameters' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YW1pcjoxMjNAcXdl' \
--data-raw '{
    "parameter": [
        {
            "name": "URL",
            "value": "http://192.168.10.120"
        },
        {
            "name": "DEVICE",
            "value": "firefox"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Many thanks. this is really valuable input, I will try. Can you share snippets examples of using this Remote API ?

Comment: @LuisTrigueiros Updated the post.